# apache giraph build error

Tags: maven, giraph

I got following error in compiling giraph.
I'm using ubuntu 16.04 with java 1.8 and maven 3.3.9. Follows detail of mvn -version command:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_171, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
```

I cloned with following comand

```
git clone http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/giraph.git
```

Hence I tryed following maven commands but I got always the same error. Could you please tell me what is my error?

1° attempt:

```
mvn -Phadoop_2 -fae -DskipTests clean install
```

2° attempt:

```
mvn -e -DskipTests clean install
```

I ALWAYS OBTAIN THIS ERROR:

```
[INFO] Compiling 994 source files to .../giraph/giraph-core/target/munged/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Giraph Parent ............................... SUCCESS [  6.020 s]
[INFO] Apache Giraph Core ................................. FAILURE [  5.081 s]
[INFO] Apache Giraph Blocks Framework ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph Accumulo I/O ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph HCatalog I/O ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph Gora I/O ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Giraph Distribution ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.821 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-05T12:01:23+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/70M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project giraph-core: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project giraph-core: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:749)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :giraph-core
```

Comment: Which hadoop version you've installed?

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, I was using jre instead of jdk. As documented, for example,
http://roufid.com/no-compiler-is-provided-in-this-environment/  or
https://coderanch.com/t/671424/build-tools/Maven-Compile-Failure-Maven-Thinks,
if JAVA_HOME points to jre instead of jdk, maven doesn't properly work. I
repeat, I'm sorry for my trivial question.

Furthermore, I was confusing by the fact that I succeed in build giraph 1.1 with jre but giraph 1.2 gives me above error if I use jre instead of jdk.